# Como puedo Mostrar los Rows de una consulta SQL con sentencia MIN en tabla html/php

Tags: php, html, sql-server, xml, tablas

un gusto saludarlos y espero puedan apoyarme, necesito mostrar los resultados de la sig: Query en PHP, pero como pueden ver lo que obtengo es un valor [0], si quito MIN(cantidad) me muestra el resultado pero de los 11 articulos de la consulta, lo que quiero es que me muestre el Min de todo el conjunto.

```
<?php
     
$sql = "
SELECT Tienda, Dia, MIN(cantidad) AS juegos <-- esto es lo que no me muestra en php/html
FROM (
    SELECT [Store No_] AS Tienda, replace(convert(varchar(11),max([Date]),106),' ','-') as Dia, 
    [Item No_] AS id_producto, 
    cast(-SUM([Quantity]) as decimal(10,2)) AS cantidad
    FROM [$franquicia\$trans_ Sales Entry] WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE [Date] $f_sql
    AND [POS Terminal No_] NOT IN ('T0265','T0266')
    AND [Item No_] 
    IN 
    ('SCPCTOI20HOMMTXXXX-1','SCPCTOI20MUJMTXXXX-1','SCPCTOI20BOTMTXXXX-1',
    'SCPCTOI20CASMTXXXX-1','SCPCTOI20NOJMTXXXX-1','SCPCTOI20NIAMTXXXX-1','SCPCTOI20ROPMTXXXX-1',
    'SCPCTOI20M2XMTXXXX-1','SCPCTOI20KDSMTXXXX-1','SCPCTOI20M1XMTXXXX-1','SCPCTOI20WOMMTXXXX-1')
    GROUP BY [Store No_], [Date], [Item No_]
) AS CTOI20
GROUP BY Tienda, Dia
ORDER BY Dia";  
        
    $result=@sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error no se pudo executar SERRAT:sqlserver: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
?>

*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/ Aqui es donde ingreso los Resultados*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/
<!--catalogo-->
<?php if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result)){?>
<table border = "1">
    <thead>
        <tr><TH COLSPAN=3 style="background-color:#FF5733">CAT. SERRAT</TH></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Tienda</th>
            <th>Dia</th>
            <th>Juegos</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <?php while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['Tienda'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Dia'];?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo number_format($row['Cantidad'],0,'.',','); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        $total += $row['Cantidad'];
        }
        ?>
</tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td align="center"><strong><?php echo $total; ?></strong></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

[![Resultado en php...][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzNKw.png

Comment: En la consulta le diste el alias **`juegos`** a la columna, por tanto si quieres obtener su valor deberías poner **`$row['juegos']`** en lugar de `$row['Cantidad']` (en todas las partes donde recuperes ese valor). Prueba si funciona, si no, haz un `var_dump($row);` y agrégalo a la pregunta para revisarlo.

Comment: Ya había probado colocando Juegos... pero me funciono var_dump($row);
Te agradezco la pronta respuesta y la atención.. @A.Cedano

Comment: No, el `var_dump` es una sugerencia temporal para verificar lo que hay en `$rows`, puede que no estuviera funcionando porque ponías `Juegos` con `J` mayúscula. Los nombres de clave en los arrays son *case sensitive*, o sea que si la columna se llama `juegos` con `j` minúscula y tú usas `J` mayúscula, no funcionará. Ahora puedes quitar el `var_dump`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `SELECT` has usado el alias `juegos` para tu columna, pero en la recuperación de los datos estás usando `Cantidad`, por tanto el valor nunca será encontrado.

Prueba a cambiar:

```
    <td align="center"><?php echo number_format($row['juegos'],0,'.',','); ?></td>
```

Y también:

```
    $total += $row['juegos'];
```

Es  importante saber que `$row` es un array, y los nombres de clave de los array son *case sensitive*  (distingue mayúsculas y minúsculas). Por tanto debes escribir cada clave cómo hayas puesto en el `SELECT`. Si pones por ejemplo `$row['Juegos']` no encontrará el dato, porque en *case sensitive*, `juegos` no es igual a `Juegos`. Conviene tener uniformidad en el código, por ejemplo en tu `SELECT` algunas columnas empiezan por mayúscula, otras no, y esto puede llevar a confusiones y a errores simples, pero que te hacen perder horas/días rompiéndote el coco.

Comment: Asi es mi estimado, Te agradezco los comentarios...

Que tengas un excelente inicio de semana, saludos